# Is there a traffic API for desktop apps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I help develop a desktop app that displays map information with various layers on top. Now we want to add the Google Maps traffic layer. We do have a developer API key.

How can I use the Google API without a website, to generate just the data layer I need and download it in KML or GeoRSS or any other format so I can use it in the desktop app on top of my own map?

We already use the distance matrix, geocode, and directions API. Is there a traffic API as well, or are traffic data only available for embedding on a website?

Comment: Can anyone also tell me why this is getting flagged as off-topic? I have a question about the Google API, how is that off-topic?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic data is not available as separate API. You can only use TrafficLayer of Maps JavaScript API or Android SDK.

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to expose these data as an API:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36537583

However, it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.